# How can you get orchids to bloom again?

Tags: diagnosis, houseplants, flowers, orchids

My aunt has several varieties of store-bought Phalaenopsis orchids which were blooming when she bought them last spring. However, after the blooms fell off, they did not bloom again.

Throughout the summer she continued to water them using the ice cube method. She kept them on a screened porch in an area where they only received morning sunlight.

The tags don't explain anything except how to water them. She has some small ones (about 4-5 inches tall when they had a flowering stalk) and some large ones (12-15 inches tall when they had a flowering stalk). They were mixed variety which she bought at the local Kroger store.

The roots still appear to be healthy and several of the plants have grown new leaves but still there have been no further blooms.

She has even tried using the "orchid food" fertilizers. Any ideas on how to help the orchids flower again?

Comment: Here is a [link to a recent thread](http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/8924/orchids-not-flowering) about reblooming these types of orchids. I hope it will give you some more information on how to proceed.

Answer (score 4):

I have occasionally had luck getting my phalaenopsis orchids to bloom by putting them in the fridge over-night.

I don't know empirically that this works, but when an orchid has been not blooming for a while I give it a try and sometimes it seems to bloom afterwards.

They definitely don't need the cold to get them to bloom, because I have plants that start blooming all the time without a cold night.

Comment: I will have to try this and see if it has any effect on her plants! Thanks!

Comment: I thought I have read that humidity plays a large role.